# Нужен совет по jquery. Кнопка "показать еще"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Попытался на сделать кнопку "показать еще", чтобы при нажатии следующий блок. Вроде получилось. Но как сделать чтобы див показать еще после нажатия пропадал, потому что если поставить display: none; она только визуально пропадает.

```
<div id='show_more' style='width:100%;height:50px;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;cursor:pointer'>
    <b class="more_b">Показать еще</b>

    </div>
    <div id='forPhotosG' style='display:none'>aaaa</div>

     $(document).ready(function () {
     var $forPhotosG = $('#forPhotosG'),
         $head_b = $('.more_b');

     $('#show_more').click(function () {
         $forPhotosG.finish();
         $forPhotosG.slideToggle("slow");
         $(this).find("b").first().css({"display":"none"})
         return false;
     });
     });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0unxumyL/1/

Есть еще вариант http://jsfiddle.net/tf5eF/167/ он мне нравится больше, но он почему то не работает у меня на сервере, хотя на jsfiddle все работает. Не пойму в чем проблема.

```
<div id="more" style="display:none;">
Тут содержимое которое будет показываться при клике на Показать еще
</div>
<div id="show-more">Показать еще</div>

  $('#show-more').click(function() {
  $('#more').fadeIn();
  $(this).fadeOut("fast");
});
```

Comment: http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: Вы обиняками пытаетесь сказать, что Вас не устраивает в фидлах, но не объясняете, какого поведения Вы пытаетесь добиться.

Comment: Не понял. Вроде все подробно объяснил. Разобрался, спасибо Рашен Беар за ссылку. Теперь осталось разобраться почему в jsfiddle второй вариант работает, а у меня на сервере нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема, по всей видимости, в том, что js надо заключать в теги `<script></script>`.

Например:

```
<div id="more" style="display:none;">
Тут содержимое которое будет показываться при клике на Показать еще
</div>
<div id="show-more">Показать еще</div>

<script>
  $('#show-more').click(function() {
  $('#more').show();
  $(this).hide();
});
</script>
```

И обратите внимание, что этот скрипт надо подключать после jquery.

Comment: Теги есть, я код просто с jsfiddle копировал. Код разместил в head, там же выше лежит '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>'

Comment: Поставьте код скрипта перед закрывающим </body>.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Вопрос решен.

Comment: @JohnDick Тогда можете принять ответ.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас клик стоит на обертку, а прячете текст внутри, но обёртка то остаётся.
Прячьте обёртку и всё будет ОК.

```
 $('#show_more').hide();
```

Comment: Это к первому или второму варианту?upd Понял, к первому

Comment: первый вариант .

Comment: Не могли бы Вы объяснить почему второй вариант работает на jsfiddle, но не работает у меня на сервере? Использую openserver

Comment: без кода я не как это не увижу, гадать мало смысла , проверьте консоль ошибки , возможно jquery не подключили...(догадки)

Comment: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>` вот это в head лежит, ниже размещен там же в head  `  $('#show-more').click(function() {
  $('#more').fadeIn();
  $(this).detach();
});`